# How to add source of review (as link) in Review Rich Snippet?

Tags: seo, schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

How to display a clickable link to the source of reviews in the Google Rich Snippet?

My JSON-LD:

```json
"review": [
{
"@type": "Review",
"name": "some topic",
"author": "all users",
"datePublished": "2016-08-02",
"description": "<a href="http://some.page.eu>check out</a>",
"reviewRating": {
"@type": "Rating",
"bestRating": "5.0",
"ratingValue": "5.0",
"worstRating": "5.0"
}
```

Comment: Could you give more details? JSON-LD (in a `script` data block) is typically hidden. Why do you want to provide a hyperlink in JSON-LD instead of HTML?

Comment: Hi unor, this is used by google search engine, and the way it is displayed as search results. I'm looking the way to not only show the 'ReviewRating" but also a source of this review.

Comment: Okay, so you mean displayed in the Google Rich Snippet, not on your page?

Comment: yes, thats I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide the URL for the review, you can use the [`url` property](http://schema.org/url).

But unless Google changes their [Review rich results](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/reviews), Google Search won’t display it.

Also note the following guideline, so if you only link to a review (instead of including the review on your page), you might not qualify:

> **Make sure the reviews and ratings you mark up are readily available to users** from the marked-up page. It should be immediately obvious to users that the page has review or ratings content.